# Making output display from javascript function and onkeydown

Tags: javascript, onkeydown

I have a question about making an output display. My code works for the most part, but only after I delete the input. For example, when I type in "0", nothing happens, but after I delete the 0 in the input, only then will it display "100%". I'm trying to make it display "100%" as soon as I put "0" in the input. To be clear, I'm not attempting to make a calculator. I'll be putting in other outputs aside from percentages.

```js
document.getElementById("myscore").onkeydown = function() {
  myJsFunction()
};

function myJsFunction() {
  var numberwrong = document.getElementById('myscore').value;
  if (numberwrong == 0) {
    score = "100%";
  } else if (numberwrong == 1) {
    score = "95%";
  } else if (numberwrong == 2) {
    score = "90%";
  }
  document.getElementById("totalscore").innerHTML = score;
}
```

```html
<p2>Number Incorrect out of 50: </p2>
<input type="number" id="myscore">

<p id="totalscore"></p>
```

Comment: Your code works as is. When I type 0 into the box `100%` appears immediately.  So, I'm voting to close as your problem is not reproducible. Having said that, your HTML is invalid, there is no such tag as `p2` (there is an `h2`). Also, you should separate your JavaScript from your HTML and not use inline HTML event attributes (`onkeydown`) and instead use `element.addEventListener()`. The only thing I can think might be your issue is that your `script` element should come just before your closing `body` tag so that by the time the script is encountered, the HTML is in memory.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Type `1` into the box and it will display `100%` immediately, not `95%`

Comment: Hmm.. when I input "2" and hit enter, it shows the correct value (90%). But it initially shows "100%" when I type in 2 *before* I hit enter. I'm trying to avoid it saying the incorrect value at first. Thanks for your fix on the other piece of code.

Comment: @Barmar The question states that upon entering `0` nothing happens and that the OP wants `100%` to display immediately after typing `0`. The code does this already. You are describing a logic error in the calculation, but that isn't what the question is asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onkeyup` rather than `onkeydown`. Your code is running before you change the value of the input.

```js
document.getElementById("myscore").onkeyup = function() {
  myJsFunction()
};

function myJsFunction() {
  var numberwrong = document.getElementById('myscore').value;
  if (numberwrong == 0) {
    score = "100%";
  } else if (numberwrong == 1) {
    score = "95%";
  } else if (numberwrong == 2) {
    score = "90%";
  }
  document.getElementById("totalscore").innerHTML = score;
}
```

```html
<p2>Number Incorrect out of 50: </p2>
<input type="number" id="myscore">

<p id="totalscore"></p>
```

Comment: ***I'm trying to make it display "100%" as soon as I put "0" in the input.*** The original code already does this.

Comment: It also does that when you put 1 into the input, which is obviously wrong, since it's supposed to display 95%.

Comment: Thank you! Elegant solution. You are awesome! I appreciate the help.

Comment: ***when I type in "0", nothing happens*** But, that's not accurate. The current code does produce output.

Comment: So sue me for answering the question he obviously meant to ask, because he didn't express the problem perfectly.